# freeing memory after you have incremented the pointer

Tags: c, free

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

```
All error checking removed from snippet - to keep the code short.
```

I have a problem freeing some memory that I have allocated and copied a string to.

My program will check for digits and increment the pointer until it gets to an non-digit.

When I go to free the memory I get a stack dump with invalid free.

I think this is because I have incremented the pointer and now it is pointing to halfway down the string, as that is when the non-digits start.
If I don't increment its ok to free. However, if I do increment it and then try and free I get the stack dump.

```
int parse_input(const char *input)
{
    char *cpy_input = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
    size_t i = 0;

    apr_cpystrn(cpy_input, input, strlen(input) + 1);



    /* Are we looking for a range of channels */
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(cpy_input); i++) {
        if(isdigit(*cpy_input)) {
        /* Do something here */
            cpy_input++;
        }
    }

    /* Where finished free the memory */
    free(cpy_input); /* Crash here */

    return 0;
}
```

I resolved the issue by declaring another pointer and assigning the address, so it points to the first character, then I free that. It works ok i.e.

```
  char *mem_input = cpy_input;
  free(mem_input);
```

My question is why do I need to declare another pointer to be able to free the memory? Is there another way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: you could use another variable to process allocated memory, where declare `cpy_input` as `char * const cpy_input`, important is you are you `free(same_address);` you got from call of  `malloc()`

Comment: You can only supply to `free()` a pointer that was previously returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.  It is not sufficient to return a pointer into the space that was allocated; it must be exactly the value that was returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the original pointer. Only the original pointer can be used when freeing the memory. You can just create another variable to hold the original pointer.

Or put the loop in a separate function. As variables by default is passed by value, i.e. copied, when you change the pointer in the function you only change the copy of the pointer.

Besides that, your loop seems a little weird. You loop using an index from zero to the length of the string, so you can easily use that index instead of modifying the pointer. Either that, or change the loop to something like `while (*cpy_input != '\0')`. I have never seen the two variants mixed.

By the way, you have a bug in that code. You only increase the pointer if the current character is a digit. But if the first character is *not* a digit, the loop will just loop until it reaches the end of the string, but the pointer will *not* be increased and you will check the first character over and over again. If you just want to get leading digits from the string (if any), you could use a loop such as

```
for (; isdigit(*cpy_input); cpy_input++)
{
    /* do something, using `*cpy_input` */
}
```

Or of course

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cpy_input); i++)
{
    /* do something, using `cpy_input[i]` */
}
```

Comment: I think it should be good practice to declare `cpy_input` as `const`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *cpy_input = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

let's say `cpu_input` is `0x1000`.  Point is same pointer should be freed in `free()`.

As per your logic if input length is 5, then after for loop `cpy_input` points to `0x1005` location. And if you calls `free(cpy_input)` it's `free(0x1005)`, which is invalid pointer for free and it's getting crashed.

Comment: actually it will be undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

you can change your loop for

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(cpy_input); i++) {
    if(isdigit(cpy_input[i])) {
    /* Do something here */

    }
```

}

or do Pointer Arithmetic to get the initial value later

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course there is another way of doing this: just decrement the `cpy_input` pointer exactly as many times as you incremented it. Or subtract the length of the string (assuming you saved it) from the final `cpy_input` value. That way you will restore the original `cpy_input` value and properly free the memory.

The bottom line here is simple: you have to pass to `free` the same pointer value that you received from `calloc`. There no way around it. So, in one way or another you have to be able to obtain the original pointer value. Saving it in another pointer is actually the best solution in your situation. But if you know how to do it in any other way - go ahead and use whatever you like most.

Answer (score 1):

`calloc` returns the pointer to memory block requested from the memory.So you can free the same pointer location only which is returned from `calloc`.

Either free the original pointer or free backup copy of this.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand, that a pointer just is a memory address.

The resource management system behind `free` and `calloc` will keep some book keeping data associated with the chunk of memory, in particular how big the chunk is, you requested by calling `calloc`. This might be in some lookup container, which stores it related to the pointer returned by `calloc` (i.e. the initial value of `cpu_input`), or this information is stored in memory right in front of the chunk, which is as far as I know more common.

If you now pass the changed value in `cpu_input` to free, it will either not find the book keeping data in its lookup container or it will look for the book keepin data in front of the pointer, where it will find the data of you string, which probably makes no sense at all.

So your solution of keeping a copy of the original pointer is an appropriate one.